How to reduce APK or Bundle size in React Native?
I have created a new project using "react-native": "0.73.6".
Without making any changes to the source code, the APK size of this project is very large.
Commands used to build the APK:
Debug build: ./gradlew assembleDebug → APK size is 52 MB and
Release build: ./gradlew assembleRelease → APK size is 18 MB
Additionally, the bundle size is 18 MB, which is also quite large since I have not made any changes in app.
I have already made the following changes in build.gradle:
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
}

After adding few screens and required npm plugins, apk size increases to 40 MB
Can anyone please let me know how to reduce APK/Bundle size in React Native?
Edit:
Android Studio APK Analyzer result


Use Android Studio integrated APK Analyzer function. Most likely a one reason for the size are the lib folders which have to contain the Hermes byte code engine and other native ReactNative libraries. That is the other side of cross-plaform development: In every app on every platform you have to include the libraries of your cross-platform runtime. BTW: 18MB isn't large for an Android app. If you want to develop apps below 18MB you have to write them natively in Java.

Yes 18 MB is not large but when I have added my few screens and required npm plugins, apk size increases to 40 MB. I have mentioned this in my question.

Check this tool https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer and work on those part or resource files while are taking more size and act accordingly.

Also keep in mind that the APK file(s) deployed via PlayStore only contain one subfolder of lib(the architecture of the device you download the app to). Therefore the final app size will be smaller. Only if you want to publish the app outside of Play Store directly by downloading an APK the app size will be as you see it now.

@Robert Thank you for your reply. I have added my Android Studio APK Analyzer result in question post. So as per above screenshot if I upload this app to google playstore then based on device architecture apk size would be 3 MB to 4 MB right?

Not 3-4MB but 5-6 MB should be realistic for the app size per architecture.

Thank you for this reply. It was helpful for me.
